# How do I turn on app update notifications?

Tags: notifications, application-autoupdate

I've got a Moto G7 running Android 10, I've had it for 2+ years.

I used to get notifications from the Play store that `App A` has updated. I haven't received these notifications in at least a year, possibly longer.

All my apps seem to be updating on a regular basis, but I have odd issues where things suddenly seem to stop working for a while and I've got no idea why. I suspect that it's because I've received an update with a feature that's now broken, and a week or so later, a fix is pushed, but since I no longer receive app update notices, it's more difficult to sort these things out.

Is there a way to (re-)enable app update notifications, either in the Play store or in the phone itself?

Comment: Are you talking about update notifications by the app itself or by Google Play Store?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, @Robert. I used to get notifications, I presume from Play store, that "App 'x' has been updated". Not that I cared all that much - I had auto-update turned on, but at least I knew that when functionality seemed to change there was a reason for it. Now I don't have a clue when an app was last updated and things change and I don't know if it's the app or my phone which I've had for 2+ years and is, frankly, showing its age...